# Showing a messagebox on a form from another controller class

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface, model-view-controller, controller

I'm using an MVC structure in my windows form application, where all of the business logic for the form is being calculated in a separate controller class. One of the challenges I'm facing is that, under certain circumstances in the controller's logic, a Messagebox needs to be shown on the form to the user. I've been trying to accomplish this by creating a new exception that will be handled on the form that will contain the message to be shown in the messagebox, but I've recently found that this probably won't be enough; I'll also need YES/NO message boxes, and messageboxes with different icons. I don't think that my custom exception can pack that kind of information within it. I've been told I might see some success if I instead use a delegate or event-type structure, but I'm not exactly sure how this would be implemented.

Any suggestions are apprecated - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are your new friend!  Create events either in the individual classes or create a new class that is shared between your classes. I use this for communicating back and forth and doing things I cannot do in my data classes.

Basically, create a **shared event** in this shared class.  Then on load of your application, add a handler for the event.  Then you can call the event anytime you want from your "controller" classes.

For example, in the shared class in your other library:

```
Public Shared Event SendMsg(ByVal sMsg As String)
```

I also create a method in that same class for calling the event:

```
Public Shared Sub SendMessage(ByVal sMessage As String)
    RaiseEvent SendMsg(sMessage)
End Sub
```

Then on your UI application, somewhere during initialization, you need to add a handler for the event:

```
AddHandler _ClsPM.SendMsg, AddressOf ShowMessage
```

Which points to a method that does the work when the event is raised:

```
Public Sub ShowMessage(ByVal sString As String)
   Try
      MsgBox(sString, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
   Catch ex As Exception
      ErrorHandler(ex)
   End Try
End Sub
```

So now, anywhere within the library, or anything that references that library, you can call:

```
[Name of your shared library].SendMessage("Hello World")
```

I use this same technique for getting data or anything else I need.

Comment: Thanks for the help and quick response! Could you provide an example of how to do this, or know of a good place to read more about it?

Comment: @user2961759 Added example